# Vuex update view on commit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm new on Vuex js and everything about stores.

I've got the following store.js

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios';


Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            pacientes: []
        },
        mutations: {
            getPacientes() {
                axios.get('http://slimapi/api/pacientes')
                .then(response => {
                    this.state.pacientes = response.data
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    console.log(e)
                })  
                }
        }

});
```

Then i do a commit when i click a button on a modal (v-dialog) calling this function

```
 agregarTurno()
  {
    axios.post('/api/pacientes/add', {

        ...

     }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });

               this.$store.dispatch('fetchPacientes')
  }
```

And then i've my turno.vue (take it as app.vue) where i retrieve the state of the store. ***However when the commit is made, the state it's not updating on the view!***.

**I'm trying to update the view when the state is changed!**

turno.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'turno',
  data () {
    return {
      pacientes: this.$store.state
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.$store.commit('getPacientes')
    },
    mounted() {
      this.$store.commit('getPacientes')
    },
  components: {
    tarjetaTurno,
    bottomNav,
    modalTurno 
  }
}
```

*I've been ready some posts, some of them talk about using computed property but i cant understand how to and if it's what i need to update the view everytime the state change.*

**Thank you everyone!**

---

---

## EDIT SOLVED

store.js

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            pacientes: []
        },
        mutations: {
            setPacientes(state, payload) {
                state.pacientes = payload.pacientes
            }
        },
        actions: {
            fetchPacientes({commit}) {
                axios.get('http://slimapi/api/pacientes')
                     .then(response => {
                        commit('setPacientes', {pacientes: response.data}); //After getting patients, set the state
                     })
                     .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e)
                     }) 
            },
            addPacientes(context){
                axios.post('/api/pacientes/add', {
                    nombre: "test",
                    apellido: "test",
                    edad: "test",
                    peso_inicial:"test",
                    patologia:"test"
                   }).then(function (response){
                        context.dispatch('fetchPacientes'); //After adding patient, dispatch the fetchPatient to get them and set state 
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                      console.log(error);
                    });          
            }
        }
});
```

Component modal which call the function to add patient:

```
  agregarTurno()
  {
    this.$store.dispatch('addPacientes');
  }
```

Turno.vue (root) who update when state changes

```
export default {
  name: 'turno',
  data () {
    return {
      pacientes: this.$store.state
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchPacientes')
    },
```

Comment: Your method getPacientes on mutation must receive the state object as parameter look at the tutorial: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#property-style-access and please don't mix portuguese with english on your code is a bad practice :) Yeah I'm brazilian too! I hope help you!

Comment: @RamonSchmidt Thank you!, i've already read the documentation but i didn't understand this kind of handling the state. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that mutations are synchronous, while you're making an `axios.get` call inside your mutation (which is asynchronous).

You should handle the `axios.get` either in your component or in a [vuex action](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html):

### Using a vuex action to handle the axios.get() call:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    pacientes: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setPacientes(state, payload) {
      // note how we don't call this.state.
      // state comes as param.
      state.pacientes = payload.pacientes;
    },
  actions: {
    fetchPacientes(context){
      axios.get('http://slimapi/api/pacientes')
      .then(response => {
          context.commit('setPacientes', {pacientes: response.data});
      })
      .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
      }) 
    }
  }
  }
});
```

And then in your component:

```
agregarTurno() {
  // commit is for mutations, while dispatch is for actions
  this.$store.dispatch('fetchPacientes')
}
```

### avoiding vuex action:

You could make the api call in your component, and then just `commit` the mutation:

```
agregarTurno() {
  axios.get('http://slimapi/api/pacientes')
  .then(response => {
    this.$store.commit('setPacientes', {pacientes: response.data});
  })
  .catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
  })
}
```

However, if several components will make this api call, you can avoid code duplication by placing it in a vuex action.

**I think that placing that kind of async code in the store as a vuex action is generally considered a best practice.**

### Some issues in your pasted code

You don't need to dispatch an action both in `created()` and `mounted()` hooks. I guess `created()` is the best option.

To make your component react to the store, setup a `data()` member that refers to the `pacientes` in the store is ok, I would do:

```
data () {
  return {
    pacientes: this.$store.state.pacientes
    }
  },
```

Now, if your component would use a lot of things of the store, I would setup a [vuex getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html).

Comment: Thank you so much!, so everytime i want to handle the store's state on a mutation i've to pass the state as a param?. Thank you for the code debugging

Comment: yes, mutations always take the `state` as the first argument, while actions always take the store as the first argument.

Comment: Do you mean 'actions always take context'?

Comment: I called the first parameter `context` in the example because that's the standard way. However, it is just a name. The important bit is that, when you `dispatch` an action from a component, passing, for instance, a list of patients, the vuex engine will call the action with the store as the first argument and the list of patients as the second. So you can call mutations from the action by calling `context.commit`. But `context` is just a param name that you can change to 'store', 'almacen' or whichever you like: the first parameter will always be the vuex store itself.

Comment: Hey @Sergeon, in my turno.vue Which would be the best practive for keep the view updated?.
 In the `data()` i return the `state`, on the `created()` i `dispatch the action`, and the same in the `mounted()`?
 Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! However it  doesn't work (in my case) returning `this.$store.state.pacientes`, it only works returning `this.$store.state`:

......And, in my `agregarTurno()` i've an `axios.post`, should i dispatch the action on the .then? since you have clarified me that axios is Async. Code updated

Comment: I found sort of weird it doesn't work. I've used to call vuex state from the @State decorator of 'vuex-class', so I'm not used to consume the store directly in plain javascript.

Comment: Nevermind. About the `axios.post`, Should the `dispatch` be on the `.then`, or outside the `axios.post`, what do you think?

Comment: you either call axios on your component, and you **commit a mutation**, or you **call axios on your action, and then dispatch it** in the component created hook. You shouldn't call axios in your component and then call an action: actions are intended to place asynchronous code -like axios calls-. There's no point on fetching the patients in your component and then call an action.

Comment: Yes, i understand what you mean, but at first -in agregarTurno- i've the axios.post (add the patient) and after adding it i want to fetch the patients and get the view updated with the new one added.
 So i should have two actions: on `agregarTurno() dispatch the action with the post` and then `dispatch the action with the fetch`? Which make the commit